# ADO recordset crashes while evaluating EOF after Excel upgrade

Tags: excel, vba, odbc, ado

I have an Excel sheet that connects to a Basis database using an ODBC connection. It worked fine when we were running Excel 2010 on Windows Server 2008, but then we upgraded to Excel 2016 on Windows Server 2016, and it doesn't work anymore.

Here's some code that demonstrates the problem:

```
Public Sub cnntest()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim sql As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.Open "DSN=redacted;UID=redacted;PWD=redacted;"

sql = "SELECT ITEM FROM IC_ITM_MST WHERE ITEM = '1400-4'"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseServer
rs.Open sql, cnn

For Each a In rs.Fields
    Debug.Print a.Name
Next a

Debug.Print rs.EOF

rs.Close
cnn.Close
End Sub
```

When I run the above code, it prints the name of the field, so I know that it's connecting to the database and executing the query. However, when it tries to evaluate `rs.EOF`, it immediately crashes and throws up an error message saying "Microsoft Excel has stopped working." It also does this when I mouse over that part of the code. The exact same code runs fine when I try it on Excel 2010 on Windows Server 2008.

Any idea why it works on the old version of Excel but not the new one? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Did the bitness of either Office or the OS change?

Comment: Everything stayed 64 bit.

Comment: What ODBC driver (name and version) are you using? Are the DSNs configured identically on Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2016? Have you applied all MS updates to Excel 2016 and Windows Server 2016?

Comment: Both computers use the BBj ODBC Driver, version 14.01.01.00. The DSNs are configured identically, and they're both set up in the 64 bit version of the ODBC manager. I'll ask about Excel and Windows updates tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four months later, I finally found the answer. I used the Windows event viewer to look at the error logs for the crashes, which said

> "Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version 16.0.4266.1001, time
>   stamp: 0x55ba1551
>   Faulting module name: BBjODBC.dll, version 14.1.1.0, time stamp: 0x5400df87
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005

This confirmed that the problem was with the BBj driver. It turns out that the person responsible for updating that driver had updated it on all of the server's hard drives except for the C drive, which was the one that Excel decided to use. As a result, we were stuck using a five year old version of the driver even though our tech people claimed everything was up to date. We're currently waiting for the driver to be updated, so hopefully that will fix the issue.