# How does one write VBA code to get data from an ODBC source?

Tags: vba, odbc

I'm looking for some straightforward documentation on how exactly to write VBA code to get info from an ODBC source.  It shouldn't be that hard, but I can't find it anywhere.

I *don't* want to populate a spreadsheet with my data.  I just want to read the data and process it using local variables, and then do other tasks in VBA based on the value of that data.

I used to think I was pretty good at searching Google for stuff, but I can't find a clear-cut example.

Can anyone point me to a reference for CRUD operations using ODBC in VBA? My "connection string" is just the name of the DSN.  I know this works, because I can use Get Data -> From Other Sources -> From ODBC and I can import the data just fine.  Therefore, I know it's not my data source that's at fault, and it's not the ODBC that's at fault.

But when I try to follow many of the examples I've found, it says, for example, to test for (rs.EOF and rs.BOF) and if they're both true, you have an empty recordset.  However, when I go to test for rs.EOF, Excel crashes.

I'm about ready to pull out what little hair remains. Are there any examples of "how to read data from an ODBC source" that are current?

Comment: Could it be an [outdated driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337981/ado-recordset-crashes-while-evaluating-eof-after-excel-upgrade)?

Comment: Googling "Excel VBA ADO DB2" should get you plenty of examples, but you seem to be having a very specific problem that those examples are unlikely to address.  Probably worth linking to your previous question, so people have some context when viewing this one.

Comment: I had actually wanted to step back and take more of a 10,000-ft view of the whole thing with this post.